# 403 Forbidden on localhost using Apache on OSX

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, osx-mavericks, http-status-code-403

Sorry if this seems trivial but the issue has been holding me up for a long time now and I'm not sure where to go with debugging it. When visiting localhost on my mac dev environment I get a 403 forbidden. Its the default set up, so this should be serving from /Library/WebServer/Documents/

When I nav straight to a file in that folder, same error. When I nav to a file that I know is not there, **same error**.

Notable settings from /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf, which appear to be all defaults:

```
ServerRoot "/usr"
Listen 80
User _www
Group _www
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Hitting localhost seems to put no entries in /var/log/apache2/error_log but if I set up a new vhosts entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Dropbox/work/web/testsite.local"
    ServerName testsite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

...and in hosts, send testsite.local to 127.0.0.1, I get this in /var/log/apache2/error_log

```
(13)Permission denied: access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/me/Dropbox/work') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

It's really stumping me. Can anyone suggest where to start?

Comment: Check the user __www_ is having permission to all the folders ( including parent directories ) to your website contents.

Comment: @Leo Prince thanks, I *think* I've done that by running 

    `chmod 755 .`

in each directory in the path, but now the error log has this:

    *[error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/me/Dropbox/work/web/testsite.local/*

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a very similar situation, no entries in error_log, etc. Very annoying.

Comment: @hisnameisjimmy sorry this is so long ago I can't remember what I did, I need to remember to come back and post solutions when I get them. It could have been related to some https stuff I'd set up to work with the weird local proxying I do. After a few months of this I eventually invested in MAMP Pro to make it easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

I futzed around with this for hours, and finally realized after comparing my setup to another machine that my httpd-vhosts.conf file had a significant difference.

On the working machine, it had:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you use vhosts, and /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf is missing that crucial part, you will struggle with localhost errors.